# Не могу вытащить значение из dictionary!

Tags: objective-c

Вот код:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);
    NSArray *values = [dictionary allValues];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [values valueForKey:@"src_xbig"]];
```

Вот что выводится в консоль:

```
(
1,
    {
    aid = "-6";
    created = 1475346651;
    height = 1600;
    "owner_id" = 387268685;
    pid = 435535181;
    "post_id" = 1;
    src = "http://cs836734.vk.me/v836734685/2d92/92R22lgR4kk.jpg";
    "src_big" = "http://cs836734.vk.me/v836734685/2d93/QSJ4LmBslYQ.jpg";
    "src_small" = "http://cs836734.vk.me/v836734685/2d91/N36BgXu2xkw.jpg";
    "src_xbig" = "http://cs836734.vk.me/v836734685/2d94/558Lo99OeIY.jpg";
    "src_xxbig" = "http://cs836734.vk.me/v836734685/2d95/dGVo-f5-Jes.jpg";
    "src_xxxbig" = "http://cs836734.vk.me/v836734685/2d96/KjRB_7NFoE8.jpg";
    text = "";
    width = 1200;
}
)
```

Comment: по моему это не dictionary

Comment: Я что-то тоже не понимаю что это)

Comment: Такое приходит после того как я хочу получить url фото пользователя из vk

Comment: ну либо пишите ответ либо удаляйте

Comment: Я написал что и где я заменил) Возможно кому-то это также поможет

Comment: в вопросе оставьте только описание проблемы, а решение перенесите в ответ

Answer (score 1):

JSON приходит к тебе не в виде словаря значений, а в виде массива.

Поэтому будет правильным следующий код

```
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[array lastObject] valueForKey:@"src_xbig"]];
```

Но я бы не советовал выписывать только одну ссылку на изображение, лучше создать класс-модуль для этого ответа и "мапить" на него ответ. Так как разные размеры изображений приходят для лучшего отображения на разных устройствах

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким образом:

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[values objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"src_xbig"]];
```